# How can I obtain the SecretManager Replica ARN via terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have configured a secret in SecretsManager to contain a replica in another region:

```
resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "api_token_secret" {

  name                    = "system/api_token"
  kms_key_id              = var.kms_keys[var.primary_region].key_id

  dynamic "replica" {
    for_each = var.replica_regions
    content {
      region     = replica.value
      kms_key_id = var.kms_keys[replica.value].key_id
    }
  }
}
```

And now I need to export for each region in parameter store a parameter containing the Secret ARN. For example:

```
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "api_token_secret_arn" {
  name  = "system/api_token/secret_arn"
  value = aws_secretsmanager_secret.api_token_secret.arn
  type  = "SecureString"
}

resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "api_token_secret_arn" {
  for_each = var.replica_regions
  provider = ??

  name  = "system/api_token/secret_arn"
  value = ??
  type  = "SecureString"
}
```

However I can't find a way to obtain the ARN for each of the replicas created for the primary secret manager and how I can dynamically change the provider to point to other regions. Does anybody know how I can achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

We need a combination of a few different features to solve this situation. First we need [provider aliases](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/providers/configuration#alias-multiple-provider-configurations). Without the question providing the information we will assume the original region is `us-east-1`, and an additional region is `us-west-1`.

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}
provider "aws" {
  alias  = "west"
  region = "us-west-1"
}
```

Now we need to determine the region in the default provider configuration:

```
data "aws_region" "default" {}
```

The region name is then available in the exported attribute `data.aws_region.default.name`.

Next we utilize the provider alias, leverage the fact that the [replica secret ARNs are identical besides the region](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/create-manage-multi-region-secrets.html), and invoke the [replace](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/replace) function to replace the original region string in the ARN with the replica region:

```
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "api_token_secret_arn" {
  provider = aws.west

  name  = "system/api_token/secret_arn"
  value = replace(aws_secretsmanager_secret.api_token_secret.arn, data.aws_region.default.name, "us-west-1")
  type  = "SecureString"
}
```

Note that provider alias parameter values cannot be interpolated with variables, and so your `for_each` meta-parameter cannot be used in the resource unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the replace suggestion, it's really useful. Sadly the lack of dynamic providers made me take a different route. Limiting the regions the user can choose from and having one resource for each one based on an activation flag :/